# How to add existing django project onto git hub

Tags: django, git, github

I have created Django python web app .How to add it to github am new to both of these and have searched web for somedays without any luck.

Comment: can you try this,its helps for me. https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for StackOverflow. There are literally hundreds of introductory tutorials on the use of git and GitHub.

Comment: I recommend this git article to all my students. Also I used this often and it is a great cheat  sheet when I forgot basic git commands. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/basic-git-commands-776639767.html

Answer (score 2):

Recommend you to look into tutorials, following code is a pointer.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'First commit'
git remote add origin <github repo link>
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to confuse you since your new to both Git and Django. So this is what I would say.

You should understand and learn git first (before continuing with Django or any other language). It's not very difficult and I would recommend doing a free 2 hours course on [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-git). Simply know that Git is an essential now days and is used for everything.

Django doesn't require Git but a good practice, you could continue without it but at somepoint in the future you probably will have to learn Git. So learn Git first and it's not difficult to learn.

**Just understand the concept of Git and why we use it.**
Learn how to use Git and things will start to make sense to you. Practice and you will understand the concept and the purpose behind it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I used to be a programmer and havent been coding for a while now.I just built a OCR based application for gaming community for scorecard extraction and wanted to upload it pythonanywhere and for uploading  using github is the prefered way .I am stuck at adding files to git repository .What I did was I went through their tutorial went to the root directory and did git init and then did git add . but I could not see the files being added to my repository .Only thing changed was inside the directory of the project the a git folder has appeared with its files .

Comment: I don't know what could be wrong but it would be useful if you could show what you are doing and maybe link to repo would also be useful.

Comment: Maybe you didn't add the files to repo or didn't push to master ?

Comment: I had to delete everything and start from scratch and then it worked directly uploaded to remote .Thanks for the help though